# Python recursively add to number if value is int else if value is dictionary then add all items from that dictionary

Tags: python, recursion

I have a dictionary which has either an `int` or a `dict` as a value.  if the value is a `dict` I would like to recursively go through the dictionary add all the possible `int` values and then again the recursiveness continues :)

I have the non-recursive code below.  anyway this could be done differently ?

```
updated_dict = {}

for k, v in aapl['income_statements'][0].items():
    if type(v) == int:
        updated_dict.update({camel_to_snake(k): v})
    elif type(v) == dict:
        val = 0
        for k1, v1 in v.items():
            if type(v1) == int:
                val0 += v1
            elif type(v1) == dict:
                val1 = 0
                for k2, v2 in v1.items():
                    if type(v2) == int:
                        val1 += v2
                    elif type(v2) == dict:
                        # etc

    final_val = val0 + val1 + val2 + val3
```

Comment: That's not recursive in the least. Have you tried implementing it with actual recursion?

Comment: You should also never do `type(..) == int`; always use `isinstance(.., int)`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = {1:{2:{3:{4:6, 5:7}, 6:8}}}

def foo(dict_d):
    res = 0
    for k, v in dict_d.items():
        if isinstance(v, int):
            res += v
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            res += foo(v)
        else:
            continue
    return res

print(foo(x))
```

Is this what you want?